# No FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS in ActionBarCompat for Android 2.3-

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

to enable/disable indeterminate progress bar. With ActionBarSherlock, it worked with all devices but when using it with ActionBarCompat, it works only for Android versions above 2.3.

I thought about using WindowCompat instead of Window but WindowCompat doesn't have FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS flag.

Comment: They've added `supportRequestWindowFeature`, maybe you should be using that?

Comment: @Delyan thank you! it works! you should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` now has `supportRequestWindowFeature`, you probably need to use that to get the full functionality.

Comment: If you used ActionBarSherlock before support library version of ActionBar, expect to have different style of indeterminate progressbar what you used to see.

Comment: I'm doing this (supportRequestWindowFeature and setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility) and its still not working...

Comment: Which theme and settings should be set for the Android L 21 build?